# R unique method ignoring by argument

Tags: r

trying to do some quick data manipulation in R, and I am very new to it.

So I am trying to use the unique function on some data, what I want to achieve is being able to keep unique rows based on some combination of columns. As I understand from the documentation this should be possible using the 'by' argument for the unique method, but as I cannot get this to work.

I have the dataTest:

```
  name age
1    A   1
2    B   2
3    C   1
```

after using `unique(dataTest,by="age")`, the output does not change while I would expect it to change to    name age

```
1    A   1
2    B   2
```

see attatchment for the code in action.

Again, its probably a beginner mistake but I cannot seem to figure it out, help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a dataframe, convert your dataframe to `data.table` and it should work. See the difference in output

1) When it is a dataframe.

```
df <- structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), age = c(1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

unique(df, by = "age")
#  name age
#1    A   1
#2    B   2
#3    C   1
```

2) After changing it to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
unique(df, by = "age")

#   name age
#1:    A   1
#2:    B   2
```

---

Another option is to use `duplicated`

```
df[!duplicated(df$age), ]
```

Comment: Thank you, converting to data.table works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   distinct(age)
```